# iterating thru cursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, cursor

I've found a good question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/oracle-automate-export-unload-of-data. Is it valid to use such a construction:

```
FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM table) LOOP
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(lfFilelog, r.row);
END LOOP;
```

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_name(DESTFOLDER in varchar2, FILENAME in varchar2)
IS
    V_FILEHANDLE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    CURSOR dataset IS 
        SELECT 
            field1, 
            field2, 
            fieldN 
        FROM 
            table1, 
            table2, 
            (SELECT field3 from table3);
        -- WHERE CLAUSE ... and so on..
BEGIN
    V_FILEHANDLE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(DESTFOLDER, FILENAME, 'w');
    FOR R IN dataset LOOP
        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_FILEHANDLE, R.ROW);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

and getting `pls-00302` error which states that I should have defined `ROW` component. So as far as I undrestand this field should already exist in the query. Am I right?

Can I simply write a row from the cursor?

Comment: `r` is already your row, so you need to do `r.column_name`

Comment: should it be written as `r.column_name%type`? Also what if I don't want to specify all column names.. there are many columns in my query?

Comment: no, needs to be the exact column name (also need `*` or columns in the `select`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer mentionned is not complete, I think it was given as an example (pseudo-code) that lacks implementation details.

As it is:

- your `SELECT` clause is invalid, you aren't selecting anything. What do you want to select?
- the construct `XX.row` where `xx` is a cursor doesn't exist
- furthermore, the [`UTL_FILE.get_line`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#i997640) procedure accepts a `VARCHAR2` as its second argument, not any kind of `rowtype`
- you can't name a table `table` (although you could name it `"table"`).

Given a table `mytable(col1, col2, ... , colN)` you could write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_name()
IS
    V_FILEHANDLE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    CURSOR dataset IS SELECT col1, col2, /*...*/ coln FROM mytable;
BEGIN
    /*utl_file.fopen maybe?*/
    FOR R IN dataset LOOP
        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_FILEHANDLE, R.col1 ||';'|| r.col2 /*...*/ || r.coln);
    END LOOP;
END;
```